# How to handle to specific object creation

Tags: c#, winforms, layout

My question is about .NET 4.6.2, Winforms and C#. Let's assume we have complex system that uses several MDI WinForm instances with very complex UI structures (user controls, dock panels, tabcontrol,etc...). The request is to prepare some minimally invasive mechanism that will extend this application with layout customization feature. The user should be able to move/resize windows content and save it. I have already implemented this customization but I need to make it loaded and saved automatically without modyfying hundreds of OnLoad() and Dispose() methods. I can imagine it as follows:
All underlying customizable components must implement ILayoutSupport interface.

```
public interface ILayoutSupport
{
   public void RestoreLayout()
   public void SaveLayout();
}
public class MyUserControl: UserControl,ILayoutSupport {...}
```

Additionally, there is a deamon service LayoutController that listens all ILayoutSupport instance creations and it:

- calls RestoreLayout each time new the instace is being created
- calls SaveLayout when the instance is supposed to be diposed.

My questions are, is this approach "architecturarly" valid?
I tried to use CreateHandle event handler in my LayoutController  service, but maybe there is better way to hook all specific types creations/disposings? I've considered to use C# attributes instead of interfaces and inject some routines into my windows, but I don't know how exactly it shoud go.
Or maybe there is better solution for my problem?
Thanks for all comments.

Comment: Instead of modifying `OnLoad` and `Dispose` for each and every form, why not just subscribe additional handlers for the `Form.Load` and `Form.Closed` events? You could centralize that code in one place.

Comment: I can't restore the layout on Form.Load handlers. Several child controls are lazy loaded so I need to restore their layout only when they are made visible so I need to do it on controls level, not on Form.Load.

Comment: Then subscribe to `Form.Shown` or one of the other events.

Comment: This is not what I need, but thanks